# Show that $\text{End}_R(R_R, R_R) = R$ as rings.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

The standard way of showing that two objects are isomorphic is by constructing an invertible function between the two. How can I do that for these two objects? I think I need a hint to construct such an isomorphism.

Comment: An module map from $R$ to $R$ takes $1$ somewhere....

Comment: Nobody should write $End(R_R,R_R)$. You can use $Hom(R_R, R_R)=End(R_R)$. The linked duplicate and its related questions show the isomorphisms for both $End(R_R)$ and $End(_RR)$.  I found the duplicate by searching "End(R)\cong R", and you should do something like that too, before asking questions.